# How to Integrate Website Game Into Facebook?

Tags: facebook, integration

I have a friend who has completed making a website game using
BASIC/ASP. We're talking the other day and we both think that it would
be cool to make this game available on Facebook.

But the problem is I am not sure where/how to start. Is it
even possible to integrate BASIC/ASP web applications into Facebook
because as I understand Facebook uses Java.

Can anyone gives us a clue or guide on how to approach this
intention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got the idea Facebook uses Java from as this is not the case. Perhaps you were thinking of JavaScript? Nonetheless it is entirely possible to host your game on Facebook - as long as you can already host it on any website. Since Facebook gives you the ability to present the user with content within an iFrame.

Essentially you just need to get your game hosted on a website somewhere and then use [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/) reference to host it on Facebook. If you want to leverage Facebook features such as invites etc then make sure to have a look around the Facebook developers website.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the route you want to go:

Here's a guide on how to make a canvas page:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/

Here's a guide on how to make a game for facebook:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/games/